# Exiting a bash shell that was started with Popen?

Tags: python, windows, bash, subprocess, popen

I can't figure out how to close a `bash` shell that was started via `Popen`. I'm on windows, and trying to automate some ssh stuff. This is *much* easier to do via the `bash` shell that comes with git, and so I'm invoking it via `Popen` in the following manner:

```
p = Popen('"my/windows/path/to/bash.exe" | git clone or other commands') 
p.wait()
```

The problem is that after bash runs the commands I pipe into it, it doesn't close. It stays open causing my `wait` to block indefinitely.

I've tried stringing an "exit" command at the end, but it doesn't work.

```
p = Popen('"my/windows/path/to/bash.exe" | git clone or other commands && exit') 
p.wait()
```

But still, infinite blocking on the wait. After it finishes its task, it just sits at a bash prompt doing nothing. How do I force it to close?

Comment: What's with the `|` character here? That's not how you pass commands to bash.

Comment: Also, why are you invoking bash at all, rather than *directly* invoking your git commands from Python? The direct route makes signal handling easier -- meaning you can easily check the status of or kill the git command itself, rather than only having a handle on the bash shell and not being able to tell what git (or other subprocesses under it) is doing.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy it is how you pipe commands in bash

Comment: Popen(['/path/to/bash.exe', '-c', 'command; command; command']

Comment: Yes, it's how you set up a pipeline in bash, but you don't run a command inside a shell by piping output from the shell into that command. `bash | git clone` takes the output of `bash` and sends that as the input of `git clone`, but `git clone` doesn't read from stdin, and bash will just sit waiting for input in that usage, which is why you get the behavior (of 'wait()' never exiting) you complain about here.

Comment: Also, according to my research, `os.Popen` passes the command to `cmd.exe`, which will be processing the pipe and the ampersands, so Bash won't even see them.

Comment: (also, `&& exit` at the end of a compound command has absolutely no effect; exiting would happen whether or not the other commands succeeded, and without any change in exit code either).

Answer (score 1):

Try `Popen.terminate()` this might help kill your process. If you have only synchronous executing commands try to use it directly with `subprocess.call()`.

for example

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["c:\\program files (x86)\\git\\bin\\git.exe",
                     "clone",
                     "repository",
                     "c:\\repository"])
0
```

Following is an example of using a pipe but this is a little overcomplicated for most use cases and makes sense only if you talk with a service that needs interaction (at least in my opinion).

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["c:\\program files (x86)\\git\\bin\\git.exe", 
                      "clone",
                      "repository",
                      "c:\\repository"],
                      stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                      stderr=subprocess.PIPE
                     )
print p.stderr.read()
fatal: destination path 'c:\repository' already exists and is not an empty directory.
print p.wait(
128
```

This can be applied to ssh as well

Comment: `p.terminate()` would help, yes, but given the usage shown here one can also address _why_ the commands are always hanging. `subprocess.call()`, by contrast, will always hang if `p.wait()` does.

Answer (score 0):

To kill the process tree, you could [use `taskkill` command on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17614872/4279):

```
Popen("TASKKILL /F /PID {pid} /T".format(pid=p.pid))
```

As [@Charles Duffy said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28532913/exiting-a-bash-shell-that-was-started-with-popen#comment45380898_28532913), your bash usage is incorrect.

To run a command using bash, use `-c` parameter:

```
p = Popen([r'c:\path\to\bash.exe', '-c', 'git clone repo'])
```

In simple cases, you could use `subprocess.check_call` instead of `Popen().wait()`:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.check_call([r'c:\path\to\bash.exe', '-c', 'git clone repo'])
```

The latter command raises an exception if `bash` process returns non-zero status (it indicates an error).